# Auto running EF migrations on Azure app service

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, migration

Our app runs on Azure with read/write permission on the DB. We are not nuts about enabling EF's automatic migrations for a production application, and because the DB user account isn't owner, it doesn't have permission to run migrations anyway.

I have used with a script to run migrate.exe to apply migrations in the past, and was happy with the result. Is there a way to accomplish this on an azure app service?

Currently running the migrations right from visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a Web Job to run your migration script on a schedule, or on-demand:

[Web Job overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

You'd probably want to set up a CI deployment so that the current EF migration script is available to the job:

[Web Jobs + CI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enabling-command-line-or-continuous-delivery-of-azure-webjobs/)

[And more info](http://chriskirby.net/deploy-your-webjob-projects-with-your-azure-website-using-continuous-delivery/)

Have a good backup strategy in place for your database, so you can smoke test completed migrations in a staging environment (preferably in an automated fashion) before flipping it into production.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I already have CI deployment working. So this shouldn't be too hard. For some reason I thought web jobs were for different purpose that this, but this looks like it will work.

Comment: So I have a .ps1 script which runs migrate.exe and applies the migrations. Under the Add WebJob of azure, the there is the option to run continuously or via trigger. How would I run my script after the site as successfully built? I was hoping there was a 'Post Deployment trigger' to run the script on, similar to what Octopus has.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to get a web job to run immediately after deployment, and then not-again until after deployment. I tried using 'Continuous', which makes it run immediately after the deployment, then just keeps running the script again and again.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is making a small console application as a web job, which I set up to be manually triggered. This ensures that my migrator.exe gets built and placed in a place I know.

```
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Log("Starting");

        var cs = GetConnectionString(args);
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(cs))
        {
            Log($"Connnection must be passed as a command argument, or in the environment variable {ConnectionStringVar}, or in the appSetting {ConnectionStringVar} (in that order).");
            Log("Exiting without running migrations.");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var c = new Configuration();
            c.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(cs, "System.Data.SqlClient");

            var migrator = new DbMigrator(c);
            Log($"{migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Count()} pending migrations");
            migrator.Update();

            Log("Complete");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log($"Failed: {e.GetType().FullName} {e.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Then I generated a custom deployment script: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script

In that script, I call my migrate.exe which runs the migrations. Has been working quite well.